# WSO2 ESB- Error Handling - On Error Sequence

Tags: xpath, error-handling, wso2-esb

For which are all the mediators **onError** Sequence works?

ex: I tried Enrich mediator it didn't work and send mediator it worked.

```
<inSequence onError="errorhandler" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" type="custom" xpath="//Body/xs"/>
    <target action="replace" property="ORIGREQUES" type="property"/>
</enrich>
```

Here  given xpath is wrong. In wso2Carbon.log  got the below message.

> ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator} - 
>   Specified node by xpath cannot be found.
>   {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator}

---

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="addTripService" context="/trip" hostname="localhost" port="8280"> <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/add/v2" faultSequence="fault">
  <inSequence onError="errorhandler">
     <enrich>
        <source clone="true" xpath="//Body/xs"/>
        <target type="property" property="ORIGREQUES"/>
     </enrich>
     <send/>
  </inSequence>
```

Here getting the error message whatever I have given in Errorhandler sequence.

This means that  **onError**  Sequence works for send mediator and not for enrich mediator. So please let me know for which all mediators it works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This [1] article contains detailed description about error handling in WSO2 ESB. Go through it and you will understand how the mediators works and how to handle the errors properly.

[1] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/10/wso2-esb-examples-best-practises-error-handling-wso2-esb/